# How can I obfuscate a string into a C++ binary?

Tags: c++, string, passwords, obfuscation

If I have a C++ code containing strings, that can be password or anything, what's the best way to obfuscate them to make very difficult the reverse engineering?
I've found some tools online, but all are not opensource.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to obfuscate a password in a binary. Just make a really obfuscated looking password. The only way that a hacker will know it's a password is by debugging your app, where no obfuscation will have any effect.

Comment: Simple: You can't. You can make it slightly harder to reverse-engineer from the source code (and even that will be easy to circumvent unless you go to great lengths implementing complex and obscure obfuscation schemes hidden behind a wall of code), but ultimately you have to decode it and then it might as well be written in plain text. If you actually want it to be secure, don't put it onto a computer controlled by someone you don't trust.

Comment: Whatever obfuscation we think of, the attacker can come to SO and find this question, so... :)

Comment: Who are you trying to guard against. 1) Little brother, 2) Another Company, 3) Another Government? 1) Use XOR 2) SSH 3) They have enough resource to break anything so don't bother (they will send the men in black suits (AKA as Lawyers)).

Comment: The password is stored as string in the source code.

Comment: how about write some inline assembly and use THAT for the password :)  so then the password is the code in a particular method.  if it has to be a string, just convert it to hex representation when using it.

Comment: Well, I suppose your password is some plain-text word that you can't easily change (e.g. it is used to login to another system).  Otherwise, you can just embed a random-generated password into your binary and strip all symbols.  I'd suggest: 1) randomly generate a key, 2) encrypt your password with the key, 3) embed the encrypted password and the key in your binary, 4) strip all debug symbols, 5) turn on optimizations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say your application uses a web service "www.example.com" and authenticates with the password, "letmein".  Compile the program and examine it with `strings`, `objdump`, or whatever:

```
$ make
$ objdump -j .rodota -s program
a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .rodata:
 4005f8 01000200 7777772e 6578616d 706c652e  ....www.example.
 400608 636f6d00 6c65746d 65696e00           com.letmein.  

$ strings program
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
__gmon_start__
...
www.example.com
letmein
```

This is pretty easy.  If you obfuscate it, you still need to put the plain text somewhere in memory before you can use it, so instead the attacker does one of the following:

- Intercepts network packets (easy, takes 5 minutes with basic knowledge Wireshark)
- Uses a debugger (easy, takes 10 minutes with basic knowledge of GDB)
- Reverse engineers your source code (hard, takes hours or days)

Note that the obfuscation tools make it harder only for attackers that are already doing it the hard way.  What's the sense in that?  All you've done is make it take 15 minutes instead of say, 5 minutes for an attacker to get the password from your executable.  Since that's pretty much the best you can do, don't work too hard on it.  Just XOR the password with some easy pattern and hope that the attackers are very lazy or stupid.

> **C-3PO:** Master Luke, sir. Pardon me for asking, but what should R2 and I do if we're discovered here?
>   **Luke:** Lock the door.
>   **Han Solo:** And hope they don't have blasters.
>   **C-3PO:** That isn't very reassuring.

(You will probably end up spending more time on this than your attacker will.)

**On the other hand:** If you are trying to prevent non-root users from accessing the password on a trusted system, you can do that with permissions & setuid binaries.

**Footnote:** The purpose of obfuscators in general is to hide program *code*, not data.  For example, if your application uses an algorithm that is a trade secret, that is when you would want to use an obfuscator.

Answer (score 7):

You should avoid put passwords as constants inside a binary. It should be configurable (e.g. by a configuration file passed in argument).

If you really need to put some password in a binary, encrypt that password and put the encrypted form as a constant in your executable.But that is not always safe (e.g. won't work against the NSA).

Don't trust any obfuscation techniques, so don't use them.

On Linux and POSIX systems, a common practice is to have built-in default for path of configuration files (and a way to set that configuration file thru program arguments). Then the configuration files use the system permissions to hide sensitive passwords. Since the configuration file has a builtin default (usually under `/etc` or `$HOME`) you can start the program without any arguments for the common case.

Notice that many programs are secure, even when their source code is freely available (a good example is `ssh`).

Read about [trusted computing base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_computing_base)

Comment: While I totally agree with your answer, I can hardly consider upvoting answer that doesn't answer anything :)

Comment: I've tried to substitute string like this "www" with \x77\x77\x77 and open the bin with an hexeditor...seems to be work very good.
Is this a good solution?

Comment: Who is your enemy? If it was me, and I was motivated enough to steal the password, it is not a good solution!!! See comment by Loki Astari.

Comment: @user1056635: you understand that putting a password in the binary has built-in obfuscation: #1: the password itself should already be a secure password, not "password123". #2: the location in the file. Who is going to know where to find your super secret password? Obfuscating further is pointless, hence why you're getting these types of responses.

Comment: Well the number is 2, but ssh is another argument for this goal.
I have a simple file that use the command openssl enc -d aes-s56-bit and I need the password inline, to read a ciphered file.
That's all. I NEED the password in the source code.
Right?

Comment: No, you need the password somewhere. In some file for instance. You don't need it in source code. For instance the `ssh` utility is reading sensitive keys from inside `$HOME/.ssh/` and that file path is indeed wired inside the binary. But not the sensitive information.

Answer (score 3):

How secure does it need to be?

If you just want to hide a password (little sister's diary security) then you could just XOR it with some random data. A determined attacker could reverse engineer the code and discover this, but they could do that however complex your solution

Comment: I've tried to substitute string like this "www" with \x77\x77\x77 and open the bin with an hexeditor...seems to be work very good. Is this a good solution?